# How to store grouped records into multiple files with Pig?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

After loading and grouping records, how can I store those grouped records into several files, one per group (=userid)?

```
records = LOAD 'input' AS (userid:int, ...);
grouped_records = GROUP records BY userid;
```

I'm using Apache Pig version 0.8.1-cdh3u3 (rexported)

Comment: Hmm it seems MultiStorage in Piggybank could be what I am looking for (?)

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pig/trunk/contrib/piggybank/java/src/main/java/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/MultiStorage.java?view=markup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 A = LOAD 'mydata' USING PigStorage() as (a, b, c);  
 STORE A INTO '/my/home/output' USING MultiStorage('/my/home/output','0', 'bz2', '\\t');
```

Parameters:

1. **parentPathStr** - Parent output dir path
2. **splitFieldIndex** - key field index
3. **compression** - 'bz2', 'bz', 'gz' or 'none'
4. **fieldDel** - Output record field delimiter.

Reference: [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.pig/piggybank/0.12.0-cdh5.2.0/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/MultiStorage.java)

Answer (score 8):

Indeed, there is a [MultiStorage](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pig/trunk/contrib/piggybank/java/src/main/java/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/MultiStorage.java) class at [Piggybank](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/PiggyBank) which does exactly what I want - it splits the records by a specified attribute (at index '0' in my example):

```
STORE records INTO 'output' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MultiStorage('output', '0', 'none', ',');
```

Comment: Do you know how to do the same but instead of specifying a compression  format, I want to store my files in RC Format?

Comment: Sorry Emtiaz, I don't know.